# Php form process some hidden filed are added automatically

Tags: php, forms

```
<form action="send_mail.php" method="post">
```

My contact form started with above code. But I don't know how has changed. Now it is :

```
 <form action="send_mail.php" method="post">
<input type='hidden' name='__token_timestamp__' value='1394868839'>
<input type='hidden' name='__token_val__' value='46fdb629bfcf8bf29d36c76be0a323cb'>
```

And similar to my register form. The form method was post but after submitting the form I see all form data through the url.

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: ,did you give submit button?

Comment: YES! anyway it is solved. Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you create your forms? Looks like the framework you are using is adding CSRF protection automatically  for you

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)
Is it a hacking process? What should i do now?

Comment: But how come the form method has changed post to get. Because all input field value are now through the url.

Comment: CSRF is a protection. how do you create your forms?

Comment: I didn't use any framework to create forms. It's just html with php form processing code.
<form action="send_mail.php" method="post"> 
 <p>
                          
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
                        </p>
                        <p><textarea name="message" id="" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required></textarea></p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" value="Send" name="contact">
                        </p>
                    </form>